# How can I perform mapreduce on mongoDB C driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I would like to perform mapreduce on mongoDB in C driver.

However, there is only one way I can successfully achieve the goal.

that is,

```
    mongo_simple_str_command( conn, "db", "$eval",legalCommand, &b )
```

Since $eval may block reading and writing process until it finished.

I have heard "mongo_run_command" can also do this.

**No matter how simple example I tried, I can't make mapreduce work on mongo C driver.**

Moreover, conn->lasterrstr and conn->errstr are nothing left.

Here is the code:

```
    bson_init( &cmd );

    bson_append_string( &cmd, "mapreduce", "country2" );

    bson_append_string( &cmd, "map"   , "function()      {emit(this.city, this.pop);}" );

    bson_append_string( &cmd, "reduce", "function(keyCustId, value) {return value;  }" );

    bson_append_string( &cmd, "out", "c" );

    bson_finish( &cmd );

    mongo_run_command( conn, "country2", &cmd, &output );//the return value is always -1
```

----databsed----

db.country2.insert({city:'tai',pop:100,land:3})

db.country2.insert({city:'pei',pop:120,land:4})

db.country2.insert({city:'kao',pop:10,land:30})

----databsed----

**Does someone can make it work or give me another way to achieve mapreduce?**

Thanks.

Comment: your reduce function doesn't actually do any reducing - what exactly are you trying to do with map/reduce?

Comment: My purpose is just to generating a collection 'c' via mapReduce function.
Acturelly, I had tried a lot of method. 
This is the simplest action that ensuring whether mapReduce works or not.

Comment: my question was more to find out if what you need to do needs mapreduce or if maybe it can be done with aggregation framework.

Comment: In fact, I am writing a mongoDB shell and trying to achieve all the function working. Therefoe I just try to make all function work in order to future using.